# Python Packages that Forecast Time Series?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

I'm wanting to build a forecasting model in Python that can predict customer exits at a company's premises each hour of the day. To start off I just want to consider historical exit times in the model, but in the future I'm going to want to incorporate other variables such as reservation times for different events we know that customer's have planned throughout the day. Are there any packages in Python that would fit a situation like this well?

Comment: [Time Series Forecast : A basic introduction using Python.](https://medium.com/@stallonejacob/time-series-forecast-a-basic-introduction-using-python-414fcb963000)

Answer (score 0):

You start with: statsmodels: (http://www.statsmodels.org/stable/tsa.html) Simple models such as univariate autoregressive models (AR), vector autoregressive models (VAR) and univariate autoregressive moving average models (ARMA) can easily be done.

Short Lectures on Time Series using statsmodel(https://github.com/mscharth/forecasting/blob/master/README.md)

There is also Prophet(https://github.com/facebook/prophet) forecasts for time series. Easy to use.